# Lingo giving an infeasible solution because of an unrelated variable?

Tags: optimization, lingo

I am working on a lingo file for production and I am using derived sets to basically get the connection down between the 2 tables. For one table, I was just trying to sum the values from the BOM table into a variable. To be clear, I'm just assigning a sum to one variable in a table. It's not a constraint at all. Why does my problem say it's infeasible when I run with that line of code. When I comment the line, everything works fine. How should I go about doing this?

[This is the line of code i'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnE5W.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't post code as image.

Comment: Please post your code as a text instead of using images, [why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)